# less css using last-child selector

Tags: css, css-selectors, less

I am using `less` and trying to get the **last** input to have a **margin-bottom** of `10px`. Here is what I have, but it is not working, and not applying the margin-bottom on the last input. Any ideas why?

```
input {
  margin-bottom: 0px;

  &:last-child {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
}
```

And the HTML

```
<form id="auth-form">
  <input id="ember367" class="ember-view ember-text-field" placeholder="Email" type="email" name="email">
  <input id="ember368" class="ember-view ember-text-field" placeholder="Password" type="password" name="password">
  <div class="clear"></div>

  <a class="pull-left forgot-password">Forgot password?</a>
  <button class="pull-right" data-ember-action="1" type="button">Sign In</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Your last `input` is not the last child — that would be your `button`.

Use `:last-of-type` instead to select the last `input`:

```
input {
  margin-bottom: 0px;

  &:last-of-type {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
}
```