# How to write a class in class in less

Tags: css, less

Which is the best way to write a class inside a class in less? I have a table in my view, where the style is different only for the last row of the table. My less class is like below. I am not getting any error. But I  just wanted to check is this how to write a class inside another or any other better way?

```
.div-td 
{
  display: table-cell;
  border-bottom: 1px solid silver;
  padding: 0.75rem;
}
.bold-border 
{
 .div-td;
  border-top: solid #808080 !important;
  border-bottom: solid #808080 !important;
}
```

my end result is:

```
.div-td {
    display: table-cell;
    border-bottom: 1px solid silver;
    padding: 0.75rem;
}
.bold-border {
    display: table-cell;
    border-bottom: 1px solid silver;
    padding: 0.75rem;
    border-top: solid #808080 !important;
    border-bottom: solid #808080 !important;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [less css using last-child selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16404376/less-css-using-last-child-selector)

Comment: It's primarily opinion based, but if you want to select **the last row** then you should check the duplicated to see how to reduce the amount of css generated by your approach  (Will generate `.div-td:last-of-type {border-top: solid #808080 !important;border-bottom: solid #808080 !important;}` and inherit the rest of the style from the `.div-td ` class)

Comment: http://lesscss.org/features/#extend-feature or http://lesscss.org/features/#mixins-feature - by the looks, the way you do it is deprecated so you need brackets after your subclass - `.div-td();`

Answer (score -2):

If you are trying to target an element INSIDE `.div-td` then nest that style in your less code like:

```
.div-td {
  display: table-cell;
  border-bottom: 1px solid silver;
  padding: 0.75rem;
  .bold-border {
    border-top: solid #808080 !important;
    border-bottom: solid #808080 !important;
  }
}
```